# SaveFileDialog Extensions Overlapping

Tags: c#, savefiledialog

I would like to offer multiple extensions in my SaveFileDialog. I would like to have the following extensions:

#### Please see my posted answer for the solution. It was a quick fix - and a fairly dumb mistake.

```
SFD.Filter = "EXE (*.exe) |*.exe |JPEG (*.jpg)|*.jpg | MP3 (*.mp3)|*.mp3 | WAV (*.wav) |*.wav ";
```

Using the above filter, when the file type is changed, the extension is appended to the filename. I would prefer that the file extensions replace one another.

An example of what the dialog filename might look like after switching file types:

```
OutputFile.exe .jpg .mp3 .wav
```

Thank you for any help,

Evan

Comment: What do you mean by `I would prefer that the file extensions replace one another`? do you mean for example the file name chosen is `OutputFile.exe` and you want it to be replaced by `OutputFile.jpg`?

Comment: @Jalal yes this is what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to combine all extensions to one selection filter, try

```
SFD.Filter = "EXE (*.exe), JPEG (*.jpg), MP3 (*.mp3), WAV (*.wav)|*.exe;*.jpg;*.mp3;*.wav";
```

For reference, check out the remarks section of the MSDN page for [FileDialog.Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filter.aspx)

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding but I want there to be a selection of different filters. For example, if you open up paint and go to save your work you have a selection from around 10 different filters. This is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with my original code is that I had spaces between the " | " marks. Please see my answer below for a comparison.

```
SFD.Filter = "EXE (*.exe)|*.exe|JPEG (*.jpg)|*.jpg|MP3 (*.mp3)|*.mp3|WAV (*.wav)|*.wav ";
```

Notice how there are **no** spaces.

Thank you,
Evan